# How to stop ignite throwing Out Of Memory and ignitenode going down

Tags: ignite

1. Is there any way to stop crashing of apache ignite node due to out
   of memory while running select query?
2. Does ignite support any configuration to kill such queries instead of thorwing out of memory and crashing the node?

*Using apache ignite 2.7.5, 3 nodes [8gb heap each]*

Answer (score 1):

There's no such machinery in the vanilla *Apache Ignite*. But it's possible to achieve the desired behaviour in *GridGain Community Edition*. It's a [source-available](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain)
solution based on *Apache Ignite*. SQL [Memory Quotas](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/memory-configuration/memory-quotas) support that functionality there. It's also possible not to fail queries with high heap consumption, but to [spill](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/memory-configuration/memory-quotas#query-offloading) intermediate data to disk. *GridGain Community Edition* is totally **free-to-use** and can be downloaded [here.](https://www.gridgain.com/tryfree#communityEdition)